# MaterialDatePicker I want to pick the date range from it on espresso

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design, google-calendar-api, android-espresso

```
 val validators = listOf(
        DateValidatorPointForward.from(startDate),
        // DateValidatorPointBackward.before(endDateValidation)
    )

    val calendarConstraintBuilder = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        .setValidator(CompositeDateValidator.allOf(validators))
    val dateRangePicker =
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
            .setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraintBuilder.build())
            .setTitleText("Select dates").setSelection(
                Pair(
                    MaterialDatePicker.thisMonthInUtcMilliseconds(),
                    MaterialDatePicker.thisMonthInUtcMilliseconds()
                )
            )
            .build()

    homeBinding.textview.setOnClickListener {
        dateRangePicker.show(childFragmentManager, "tag")
        dateRangePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
            val first=it.first.convertLongToDateString()
            val second=it.second.convertLongToDateString()
          
        }
     }
```

```
// fragment test
onView(withId(R.id.textview)).perform(click())//what should i write here
```

I am trying to get the answer from here but it is not working
[text](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/tests/javatests/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePickerTestUtils.java)

I want to pick the date from materialcalender in espresso testing

Comment: @Chantell Osejo Can you please help me here

Comment: @ChantellOsejo 
 Can you please help me here